# Context-sensitive grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-sensitive-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

I'm looking for a context-sensitive grammar that describes the following language:

```
L = { ww | w ∈ {a,b}*, |w| ≥ 1} <br>
```

I've got problems with the fact that no rules such as X -> ε are allowed and therefore I can't place any nonterminal indicating the "middle" of the word.
Is there any trick to the problem? 
If you happen to know the answer, please help.

Comment: Post your question here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is actually easy. In a context-sensitive grammar, you can have strings on the LHS; that's the context. So let's say you end up with a string like this:

```
abababWababab
```

Alright, so you don't want a rule like

```
W := -empty-
```

Excellent. How about these rules?

```
aWa := aa
aWb := ab
bWa := ba
bWb := bb
```

Of course, this implies that you should avoid introducing `W` unless you're sure you're going to have a non-empty string.